# Usar certificados em aplicação web Azure depois que foi atualizado a cadeia intermediaria Raiz Brasileira v5 para autorizar NFe

Tags: nfe, certificado-digital, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma aplicação web no Azure. Tenho certificados modelo A1 com a cadeia de certificação ainda Raiz Brasileira v2. Os WebServices da receita foram atualizado para utilizar a nova cadeia de certificação conforme informação no próprio site da receita: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/informe.aspx?ehCTG=false#484

Antes da atualização, nenhum erro ocorria ao consumir um webservice como por exemplo o https://www.svc.fazenda.gov.br/NfeStatusServico2/NfeStatusServico2.asmx

Se faço a instalação das cadeias intermediárias em minha máquina local no gerenciador de certificados em autoridades de certificação confiável, e executo a aplicação local, não tenho nenhum problema.

Como faço para instalar e a aplicação utilizar estes certificados intermediários no azure?

Tentei em Subscriptions/Management certificates e também em App Services/ SSl certificates sem sucesso. Também tentei sem sucesso enviar as cadeias intermediárias juntos com o arquivo pfx.